# How do I update a value in SQL by looking up another table using that value?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table SuperKittens with a column name 'KittenId'

This value is a number, such as 12345.

I have another table called Kittens with two columns, KittenId and KittenNewId

I want to update SuperKittens and change all the KittenId to KittenNewId, using table Kittens to look up the values.

I thought something like this might work, but apparently it's not valid:

```
UPDATE SuperKittens SK 
SET SK.KittenId = 
(SELECT KittenNewId FROM Kittens K WHERE K.KittenId = SK.KittenId)
```

Any ideas?

Edit: The error I got is that it's invalid SQL:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'SK'.
```

Comment: Do you get a error message or does the query simply do nothing?

Comment: Doesn't your query work? it should be ok.

Comment: What is the error? It could be query returning multiple rows or error update identity column or something else.

Comment: I have put the error into the question

Comment: @SLC .. Based on your error you have some answers already from RT and SEBB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
UPDATE SuperKittens SK 
SET SK.KittenId = K.KittenNewID
FROM Kittens K INNER JOIN  ON SK.KittenId = K.KittenId
```

or you may try with Merge option like this:

```
MERGE INTO SuperKittens SK 
   USING Kittens K
      ON SK.KittenId = K.KittenId 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET SK.KittenId = K.KittenNewID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative;

```
UPDATE SuperKittens SK
SET SK.KittenId = K.KittenNewID
FROM Kittens K
WHERE
K.KittenId = SK.KittenId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your query this way:

```
UPDATE SuperKittens SK, Kittens K
SET SK.KittenId = K.KittenNewId
WHERE K.KittenId = SK.KittenId
```

I have tested it in Access and it works ;-)

Comment: I get 'incorrect syntax near SK expecting SET'. It doesn't like me giving the SuperKittens a variable name.